# Как можно отсортировать список объектов по дате которая хранится в String?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как можно отсортировать список объектов по дате которая хранится в String?
Список из объектов List по дате хранящейся в lastMessage в updateAt.
Во первых я полагаю нужно парсить дату как-то так

```
val date = gr.lastMessage.updatedAt.substring(0, 16)
            val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm")
```

классы Group и Message

```
class Group(val topic: String,
                    val name: String,
                    val lastMessage: message?,
                    val id: Int) 
class Message(val id: String,
                   val updatedAt: String,
                   val insertedAt: String,
                   val body: String?,
                   val authorId: String)
```

Comment: нет, нет, думаю есть решение проще. Используйте компаратор для сравнения объектов и сортировке. Сразу ищите компаратор по датам

Answer (score 1):

можно ведь просто сравнивать строки

> В Java compareTo() получает значение 0, если аргумент является строкой
>   лексически равной данной строке; значение меньше 0, если аргумент
>   является строкой лексически большей, чем сравниваемая строка; и
>   значение больше 0, если аргумент является строкой лексически меньшей
>   этой строки